# Парсинг XML в oracle SQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmlparser, plsql

Добрый день!

Есть BLOB содержащий примерно такие данные:

```
<Data>
  <Name>Data1</Name>
  <Value>Data1_1</Value>
</Data>
<Data>
  <Name>Data2</Name>
  <Value>Data2_2</Value>
</Data>
```

Задача вытащить только **Data2_2** при помощи **extractvalue()** ориентируясь на **Data2**.
Как? Через xmlsequence() не получилось.
Пожалуйста, подскажите, куда копать, желательно с примером :)

Спасибо!

Comment: PS для значений **Data2_2** есть регулярки...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в BLOB хранится xml и в нем есть корневой элемент (я подставил root), то можешь использовать такой подход

```
WITH tmp AS
  (
    SELECT
      '<Root>
        <Data>
          <Name>Data1</Name>
          <Value>Data1_1</Value>
        </Data>
        <Data>
          <Name>Data2</Name>
          <Value>Data2_2</Value>
        </Data>
      </Root>' x
    FROM
      dual
  )

SELECT
  extractvalue(VALUE(b),'Data/Name') name,
  extractvalue(VALUE(b),'Data/Value') value
FROM
  tmp,
  TABLE(xmlsequence(extract(XMLTYPE(tmp.x),'Root/Data'))) b
WHERE
  extractvalue(VALUE(b),'Data/Name') = 'Data2'
```

Comment: Ограменное спасибо, благодоря этому примеру у меня выпрямились руки относительно xmlsequence().